# когда делаю migrations выдаёт ошибку: The entity type 'Person' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

когда делаю migrations выдаёт ошибку:

> The entity type 'Person' requires a primary key to be defined.

Мой код:

```
public class Person
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Order_Product { get; set; }
}

public class Information
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class VideoGamesDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Information> Informations {get; set;}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost,2727; Database=Persons; User=sa; Password=Pa$$word1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Изменить заголовок, чтобы была понятна решаемая задача

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте поле

```
public int PersonId { get; set; }
```

или просто

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Согласно текущим соглашениям EF автоматически распознает по наименованию первичный ключ.

Альтернативный вариант - не менять наименование поля, а проставить атрибут [Key] над полем, которое у вас первичный ключ (я правда не уверен, что это именно это поле первичный ключ)

```
[Key]
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
```

Но это вариант не так удобен, когда вы будете указывать внешние ключи - они автоматом не подцепятся и придётся прописывать атрибуты. (Впрочем - может вам так нравится, ручной контроль и т.п.)

Обратите внимание, в Informations у вас тоже нет ключа.

Ссылки по теме:

- https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx